# Randomized Assignment Problem

Tags: randomized-algorithms, linear-programming, randomness, linear-algebra, assignment-problem

Given $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n\in \mathbb{R}^d$ find a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P\in\mathbb{S}_d$ that minimizes $\sum_{ij}P_{ij}|x_i-y_j|$.

This is an assignment problem and can be solved in $O(n^3+n^2d)$ time using the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Suppose $x_i\sim N(0, I_d)$ and let $v=\mathbb{E}_{x_1,...,x_n}\left[\min_{P\in\mathbb{S}_d} \sum_{ij} P |x_i-y_j|\right]$. Does anyone know of an algorithm that can compute $v$?

I'm also interested in algorithms for other distributions, e.g., $x_i\sim U(0,1)^d$ or $x_i\sim L(0,1)^d$.

Comment: Simple approximation algorithm: sample $S=\{x_1,...,x_d\}$ and solve the resulting assignment problem in $O(n^2d+n^3)$ time. The result is correct in expectation (is unbiased). We can reduce variance by averaging the result of $t$ samples $S_1,...,S_t$. The variance is reduced by a factor $1/t$ and takes $O( tn^2d + tn^3)$ time.

Comment: [1] discuss a type of random assignment problem where $C_{ij}=|x_i-y_j|$ are independently and identically distributed. If $x_i\sim U(1,2)$ and $y_j<1$ then $|x_i-y_j|\sim U(1-y_j, 2-y_j)$ but I'm not sure that the $C_{ij}$'s as there is some common dependency on $y_j$. 

[1] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01299451

Comment: The following might also be interested, but it seems it is hard to solve an easier problem.. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221707011460